# GitHub Action Unrecognized named-value: 'env'

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to create some GitHub Action and I get stuck with the following issue. I am specifying the virtual machine where it is supposed to run as an environment variable so it can be easily identified, also we are looking to use it as a template for future actions.
**YAML:**

```
# This workflow will build a .NET project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testi

name: xxxxx
run-name: xxxxx
env:
  buildConfiguration: Release
  dotNet: '7.x'
  project: check.csproj
  projectPath: ./xxxxx/xxxxx
  releaseDirectory: ./xxxxx/xxxxx/bin/Release
  virtualMachine: ubuntu-latest
  workingDirectory: 'xxxxx/xxxxx
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - development
      - release/*
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      Verbose:
        description: 'Will output messages which could be useful for debugging.'
        default: false
        required: true
        type: boolean
jobs:
  check:
    name: 'Check'
    runs-on: ${{ env.virtualMachine }}
    steps:
  - name: 'Check out repository code'
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: 'Nuget Tool Installer'
    uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
  - name: 'Restore Project'
    working-directory: ${{ env.projectPath }}
    run: nuget restore ${{ env.project }} -PackagesDirectory ${{ env.projectPath }}
  - name: 'Setup .Net'
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
    with:
      dotnet-version: ${{ env.dotNet }}
  - name: 'Build Project'
    working-directory: ${{ env.projectPath }}
    run: dotnet build ${{ env.project }} --configuration ${{ env.buildConfiguration }}
  - name: 'Run xxxxx no verbose'
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' || inputs.Verbose == false  }}
    working-directory: ${{ env.workingDirectory }}
    run: ./xxxxx
  - name: 'Run xxxxx verbose'
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' && inputs.Verbose == true  }}
    working-directory: ${{ env.workingDirectory  }}
    run: ./xxxxx -Verbose
```

**Error:**

> Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/xxxxx.yaml#L30 The workflow
> is not valid. .github/workflows/xxxxx.yaml (Line: 30, Col: 14):
> Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within
> expression: env.virtualMachine

Do you know how should I call them? I am running the same file locally on my machine with nektos/act and it works.

Comment: According to the [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability), `env` context is not available under `runs-on`. You may use `vars` context instead.

Comment: There's a closing single quote missing on the `workingDirectory` line.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in above workflow. You can use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to fix those.